# Unexplained Infinite Loop in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am learning Tkinter for python2 where i came across this code.this creates a window in tkinter and increments the value of label every 1 second While the code runs perfectly fine..Can you tell me why an infinite loop is not observed as after every thousand seconds the control return to `count()` and control should have never reached the last line of code?

```
import Tkinter as tk

counter = 0 
def counter_label(label):
  def count():
    global counter
    counter += 1
    label.config(text=str(counter))
    label.after(1000, count)
  count()


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Counting Seconds")
label = tk.Label(root, fg="green")
label.pack()
counter_label(label)
button = tk.Button(root, text='Stop', width=25, command=root.destroy)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Also the label variable passed to the function `def counter_label` is just a copy of original variable so changing it shouldnot affect the original variable.How is it happening?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: edited the post to include second question.

Comment: Solved my second question..The `label` object is mutable .Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 1000 is measured in milliseconds i.e., it is 1 second
2. `count()` is reached and it is an infinite loop (if `root.mainloop()` is running).

`label.after(1000, count)` schedules `count` function and returns immediately. The tkinter event loop should be running otherwise `count()` won't be called again.

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful.From what I understood `label.after()` method doesnt holds the control for 1s it justs schedules another task and passes the control.Am i correct?

Comment: @freeza: yes. It returns at once.